# PUP injecting scripts on every site I visit

Tags: virus, html, malware, javascript

I left my cousin alone for 5 minutes and he managed to mess up my system. 
I think it's some PUP which opens pop-ups to sites that benefit the creator of it. Luckily I don't get any pop-ups. I think that's because of the built-in ad blocker I have in Opera. I thought I managed to remove the PUP by deleting Appdata folders and editing the Registry, however I noticed that some code which was being injected at the bottom of the `<head></head>` tags of whatever site I visited.

A pretty lengthy:

```html
<style type="text/css">
With a lot of classes and links to inappropriate sites.
</style>
```

I've formatted it for you, Here it is: https://jsfiddle.net/yxuqwkt5

I've run system scans on Malwarebytes. Needless to say nothing has been detected.

Comment: It does.not make sense that this javascript is being injected by malware. Are you sure you are not just looking at multiple sites all of which use Google analytics? Check the identifier UA-* across multiple domains.

Comment: You're right. the 2 sites I've been comparing happen to both use Google Analytics. however on what other site I might go to that `<style type="text/css">` Is being injected at the bottom om the `<head>`